# Check whether the second number is greater than or less than to first number

Tags: c, conditional-statements

Im doing an testing program. There will be 2 inputs, first number and second number.Check the first number if it is greater than or less if the first number is less to second number. The user will input again the "Enter second number", i dont know how should I do the do while in there. thanks

This is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int number1,number2,total;
    printf("Enter first number");
    scanf("%d",&number1);
    printf("Enter second number");
    scanf("%d",&number2);
    if(number1 > number2)
    {
      total = number1 - number2;
      printf("%d",total);        
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Number 1 is less than to number 2");
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: It's hard to understand what's your problem.

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: Your asking us how to do a while loop in your code to read user input? [Have you tried googling it?](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=read+user+input+in+a+loop+c)

Comment: @WeatherVane I think this is homework, giving the direct answer may not be helpful?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a loop function with user input in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16248841/how-to-use-a-loop-function-with-user-input-in-c)

Comment: Hmm im doing a project not homework, this validation is needed that's why I asked here

Comment: So, if that is for your job, you first should work through a C book.

Comment: @Blacksmith what does that have to do with this question? Please ask a new one.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int number1, number2, total;

    printf("Enter first number >");
    scanf("%d", &number1);

    while(1){
        printf("Enter second number >");
        int status = scanf("%d", &number2);//check return value of scanf
        if(status == 1){// read integer but No check such as 3.5, 3?
            if(number1 < number2)
                printf("Number 1 is less than to number 2\n");
            else
                break;
        } else if(status == 0){//can't read integer
            printf("invalid input.\n");
            scanf("%*[^\n]");scanf("%*c");//clear up to newline
        } else {//if(status == EOF){//you want finish ;-)
            puts("bye");
            return -1;
        }
    }

    total = number1 - number2;
    printf("%d\n", total);      

    return 0;
}
```